# Proportional Free Transform

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'd like to perform a proportional transform on an image in photoshop.

I'm looking to do this automatically using the javascript interface. I'm kinda familiar with doing this sort of stuff. To do a transform, one must utilize the photoshop actionscript language via the scriptlistening plugin as the transform function is not exposed in the DOM.

I'm not so familiar with what these variables are doing and I'm having a lot of trouble determining how to make my transform proportional (i.e. don't change aspect ratio as we enlarge/shrink).

Anyone else familiar or have any ideas?

```
var idTrnf = charIDToTypeID("Trnf");
var desc22 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
var ref12 = new ActionReference();
var idLyr = charIDToTypeID("Lyr ");
var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID("Ordn");
var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID("Trgt");
ref12.putEnumerated(idLyr, idOrdn, idTrgt);
desc22.putReference(idnull, ref12);
var idFTcs = charIDToTypeID("FTcs");
var idQCSt = charIDToTypeID("QCSt");
var idQcsa = charIDToTypeID("Qcsa");
desc22.putEnumerated(idFTcs, idQCSt, idQcsa);
var idOfst = charIDToTypeID("Ofst");
var desc23 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idHrzn = charIDToTypeID("Hrzn");
var idPxl = charIDToTypeID("#Pxl");
desc23.putUnitDouble(idHrzn, idPxl, 622.000000);
var idVrtc = charIDToTypeID("Vrtc");
var idPxl = charIDToTypeID("#Pxl");
desc23.putUnitDouble(idVrtc, idPxl, -480.500000);
var idOfst = charIDToTypeID("Ofst");
desc22.putObject(idOfst, idOfst, desc23);
var idWdth = charIDToTypeID("Wdth");
var idPrc = charIDToTypeID("#Prc");
desc22.putUnitDouble(idWdth, idPrc, 150.000000);
var idHght = charIDToTypeID("Hght");
var idPrc = charIDToTypeID("#Prc");
desc22.putUnitDouble(idHght, idPrc, 150.000000);
var idIntr = charIDToTypeID("Intr");
var idIntp = charIDToTypeID("Intp");
var idBcbc = charIDToTypeID("Bcbc");
desc22.putEnumerated(idIntr, idIntp, idBcbc);
executeAction(idTrnf, desc22, DialogModes.NO);
```

**idPrc** is what I use to change the percent of the transform. but I'm not sure what **idHrzn** and **idVrtc** are doing and how I can generate the right number such that the transform will not change the aspect ratio of the iamge.

Comment: There's [a bunch of scripting interfaces](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html), which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using the CS6 javascript reference, but for the most part they aren't significantly different. This question is really directed more at photoshop inner functionalities than anything else.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're really trying to do.  If you're just resizing the image, why don't use you 'resize' method in the dom?

Comment: That is a great point Anna, however, I'm still curious as to how photoshop is using these two other variables for this function, and image resizes aren't proportional so I will have to do the subsequent math.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [Anna Forrest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1760684/anna-forrest) in the comments there's no need to use the script listener to do a proportional resize specified by a percent.

```
#target photoshop

main ();

function main ()
{
    if (app.documents.length < 1)
    {
        alert ('No document open to resize.');
        return;
    }

    // Make the image 50% smaller.
    var resizePercent = 0.5;
    // You might want this to be something else depending on the image content...
    var resampleMethod = ResampleMethod.BICUBIC;

    // Apply the resize to Photoshop's active (selected) document.
    var doc = app.activeDocument;

    // Get the image size in document units.
    var resizedWidth = doc.width.value * resizePercent;
    var resizedHeight = doc.height.value * resizePercent;

    // Apply the change to the image.
    doc.resizeImage (new UnitValue (resizedWidth, doc.width.type), new UnitValue (resizedHeight, doc.height.type), doc.resolution, resampleMethod);
}
```

Comment: Rich, thanks for taking your time out to comment on this 5 month old question. To clarify in case it wasn't. I'm aware a proportional image resize can be achieved using the resizeImage function, however, my interest is in understanding what is required to script a proportional free transform, without using the image resize function, in order to better understand how free transform works. Perhaps it's a bit academic for you. Thanks again!